# What is the way of reordering columns as the same data in each different columns?

Tags: r

I want to find a way to extract only the same data from the values ​​in column A and column B and sum the extracted values in column C. This is just sample of my huge data..

```
X=data.frame(A=c(1:5),  A1=c(53,15,25,3,5))
X
    A   A1
1   1   53
2   2   15
3   3   25
4   4   3
5   5   5


Y=data.frame(B=c(5,1,2,11,62,22),  B2=c(13,11,23,42,11,88))

    B   B2
1   5   13
2   1   11
3   2   23
4   11  42
5   62  11
```

extracted same values between A and B and show with sum of  A1 and B2 data (C=A1+B2)

My expect result is :

```
    A   B   C 
1   1   1   64
2   2   2   38
3   5   5   18
```

THANKS!!

Comment: Is the comparison rowwise? Columwise?Datawise? What defines "same"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
X <- data.frame(A=c(1:5),  A1=c(53,15,25,3,5))
Y <- data.frame(B=c(5,1,2,11,62,22),  B2=c(13,11,23,42,11,88))

Z <- merge(X,Y, by.x = 'A', by.y = 'B')
Z$C <- Z$A1 + Z$B2
data.frame(A = Z$A, B = Z$A, C = Z$C)

  A B  C
1 1 1 64
2 2 2 38
3 5 5 18
```